# Why are the standard errors of these two outputs so different?

Tags: r, regression, standard-error

Context of the question:

Two professors want to look at the effect of students’ high
school math marks on their marks in their first calculus course. All marks are between 0
and 100. Using data from 1000 students, Professor 1 fits a simple linear regression
model with calculus mark as the response and mark in Grade 12 math as the predictor.
Professor 2 fits the same model but also includes marks in Grades 9, 10, and 11 math as
predictors. Some output associated with the fitted models is given below. What is the
most likely reason that the standard error of the estimated effect of Grade 12 mark is so
much higher in Professor 2’s output than in Professor 1’s output?

[image]

I don't understand why the addition of grades 9-11 so heavily impacts the standard error of the estimated effect.

Comment: What is the estimated effect? That is not obvious from the screenshots.

Comment: Please search our site for "multiple regression" and include the keyword "multicollinear*".  We have a *tremendous* number of posts related to this topic.  Other related searches could look for "controlling" for variables; for changes in "significance"; and for "moderation" and "mediation."